# Installing Zabbix-agent2 on amazon linux2

Tags: software-installation, amazon-linux, zabbix

I am trying to install zabbix-agent2 as mentioned in this [link](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/concepts/agent2) agent 2 is available in pre-compiled Zabbix packages.

I ran

> rpm -Uvh
> https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/5.4/rhel/8/x86_64/zabbix-release-5.4-1.el8.noarch.rpm

Then search for Zabbix-agent2 using yum and it shows available. However, when I try to install using

> Sudo yum install zabbix-agent2

It shows Error: Package: zabbix-agent2-5.4.9-1.el8.x86_64 (zabbix)
Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)

How can I resolve this? Is there any alternative way to install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Linux 2 is based on RHEL 7 and is still using `glibc 2.26`. You are installing the package from the Zabbix repo that is based on RHEL 8 which requires `glibc 2.28` which is more recent. You can't upgrade `glibc` because the basic functionality of the OS depends on a specific version.

What you need to do instead is to use the Zabbix repo that is based on RHEL 7 and install `zabbix-agent2` from there:

```
yum install https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/5.4/rhel/7/x86_64/zabbix-release-5.4-1.el7.noarch.rpm

yum install zabbix-agent2
```

You can also use `rpm -Uvh` to install the `rpm` for the repo in the first step but it makes no difference.